# Add 15% to price between brackets in string using preg_replace

Tags: php

I have some strings that I need to find the number between the < > brackets, I found a post on stack overflow and I am trying to use the code I found there

```
$colops = preg_replace_callback( '/\<(\d+)\>/', function( $match) {
    return '<' . ($match[1] * 1.15) . '>';
}, $row_products['colops']);
```

My strings look like this

> No Storage<118.54>, Storage 2 Drawer<158.54>,Storage with
>   Slider<138.54>

Am I doing this right, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That look right to me, except that you don't need to escape the `<` and `>` in your regex as they have no special meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` will match only digits. It seems you need to match dots too in order to catch things like `118.54`.

Your expression should be something more like this:

```
$colops = preg_replace_callback('/\<([\d.,]+)\>/', function($match) {
    return '<' . number_format(floatval($match[1]) * 1.15, 2) . '>';
}, $row_products['colops']);
```

Comment: dots and commas have no special meaning inside character classes - no need to escape those.

Comment: @Havenard Don't need to escape `<` and `>`. Those characters have no special meaning in regular expressions.